Latex Workshop send the wrong svg file path to Inkscape
I'm on an Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS machine, using vscode 1.95.1 and the LatexWorkshop 9.14.1 plugin. I have been writing a document using the acmart document class without problem until now.
But I am having issues with adding a svg image in the document. I attempted to use the svg package, but the compilation fails with this error:
[Builder] Recipe returns with error code 12/null on PID 10543.
[Builder] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-linux:/opt/ros/humble/bin:/home/user/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/user/.cabal/bin:/home/user/.ghcup/bin, $Path: undefined, $SHELL: /bin/bash
[Builder] 
** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:10689): WARNING **: 11:36:39.285: Can't open file: /home/user/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:10689): WARNING **: 11:36:39.286: Can't open file: /home/user/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/home/user/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /home/user/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!

Now, I see there that the path /home/user/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg is wrong, and it should be something similar to /home/user/workspace/latex/project/figures/platform_pie_chart.svg. I could not find a way to use make latex workshop use the correct one. I am properly adding the -shell-escape option to the latex compiler as explained here, and I attempted to use \svgpath{{<path1>}{<path2>}} as explained in the svg package documentation, but it had no effect.
The following is a clean tex code that reproduces the issue.
\documentclass[acmtog, nonacm, balance=false]{acmart}
\usepackage{svg}
\svgpath{{figures/}{/home/user/workspace/latex/project/figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includesvg[width=\textwidth]{figures/platform_pie_chart.svg}
  \caption[Platform distribution chart]{Pie chart describing the distribution for data.}
  \label{fig:platform_pie_chart}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
\endinput

As for the compilation, I'm using almost the default one provided by Latex-Workshop, with the added -shell-escape argument. In the setting.json file is like this.
"latex-workshop.latex.tools": [

    {
      "name": "latexmk",
      "command": "latexmk",
      "args": [
        "-shell-escape",
        "-synctex=1",
        "-interaction=nonstopmode",
        "-file-line-error",
        "-pdf",
        "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
        "%DOC%"
      ],
      "env": {}
    },
    <other commands>
]


Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short TeX code resulting in your issue and include to your question how you compile?

@Mensch I updated the original question.

try putting the .svg in your working directory with your .tex file. does it compile then? if not, try compiling on the command line in the working directory with the files present. unless the problem disappears when you remove your bibliography, please delete this from your example. only you have mybib.bib so, if that is necessary to reproduce the issue, we'd need a copy of that, too.

@cfr The bibliography is not necessary, I left it to see if the other commands of acmart still worked as intended if I removed the figure.

We did have the same question before though, see this specific answer.

I think I found the problem. I attempted to compile the project on different machines (with different ubuntu and vscode versions). Some managed to compile it without problems, other showed the same error. After checking all the components I narrowed it down to Inkscape installed via snap. The machines which had Inkscape installed via PPA had no problem in compiling the project.
I uninstalled Inkscape from snap and installed it via PPA and that was enough to make the project compile properly. At the end I couldn't find out why Inkscape from snap didn't work though.

Snap packages are sandboxed with a quite strict filesystem access policy, which creates many problems in a wide variety of use cases. This Inkscape problem is one of them, but also for example the Firefox snap does not allow to open files outside of /home, which means you can't read the documentation for the tex4ht LaTeX package (which is in html and stored in /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/doc in the apt version). Also for a long time hyperlinks from Evince could not be opened in Firefox (but that has been fixed), Firefox can't write temporary download files to /tmp so they [...]

[...] are automatically deleted, updating is more invasive and slow, starting the applications is slower, more disk space is needed, etc. etc. I try to avoid such issues by installing applications from a PPA whenever possible, or even from source, and only using snap versions when there is no (practical) alternative.
